# Blazor Standalone PWA offline Authentication/Authorization with AAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-page-application, blazor, progressive-web-apps, azure-ad-msal

I had a look a lot of days to find a solution for my problem regarding offline authentication of a user in my `Blazor Standalone PWA`.

With .Net 5.0 I changed the Authentication scenario on `Azure AD` from `Web` to `SPA`.
After that change, my PWA was not able to login the user in offline mode.
I work on `Program.cs` with AddMsalAuthentication and save the tokens and ID's in local storage with help of `MSAL`.

If I'm online everything works like expected and I can login with the users and the tokens will be stored in local storage.
After changing the online state, the PWA try to get the openid-configuration data from azure.
I tried to also serve this request with the service worker, which worked quite fine but the token request after that fails also.

I searched and found the [CarChecker](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/CarChecker) app and the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/progressive-web-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#interaction-with-authentication) as well but this didn't solve my problem.
Did I missed something or is there really no way, to make offline auth workable on Blazor Standalone PWA's?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this?

Comment: Not until now but also didn't have enough time to have a look at it again.
Will continue my project this winter so hopefully I will find a proper solution for that.